# Create Color Ramp for polygon outline in QGIS 2

Tags: qgis

I was wondering if it was possible to create and save a colour ramp that colours the outlines of polygons rather than the fill in QGIS rather than editing each symbol manually.

Answer (score 10):

I set the Symbol Layer Type to 'Outline: Simple Line' then selected the color ramp, then selected 'Classify'